# Copy from type and then add further properties

Tags: typescript

I have a type in my component. I want to copy that type while excluding one property from the original type, and then add further elements to the copied type. Is that possible?

For example

```
type Person1 = {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    job: string;
}

type Person2 = Omit<Person1, 'job'>; // this is basically type {name: string; age:string;}
```

How do I add further properties to Person 2. For example, their country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `&`:

```
type Person1 = {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    job: string;
}

type Person2 = Omit<Person1, 'job'> & { country: string };
```